# Including ManagedObjectModel in a Framework

Tags: ios, core-data, frameworks, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I am developing a framework for which I would like to include an `NSManagedObjectModel` with abstract entities that are designed to be subclassed in the application. Is it possible for an application to subclass entities in the `NSManagedObjectModel` in the framework?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can subclass classes from a framework. There is no reason why subclassing should not work.

If you want to extend the `NSManagedObjectModel` from the framework in the app it might get tricky, but it could work as well. You should try it out and ask a new question when you hit a more concrete roadblock.